# SQL Query performing slow on SQL Server 2016 SP1 than SQL Server 2012 SP3

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a SQL query which runs under 1 minute on SQL Server 2012 SP3 but run over 2 hrs on SQL Server 2016 SP1.on Server side both server runs on identical hardware which is virtual server (VMWare),2 sockets 16 vCPUs with 170GB RAM allocated to SQL Server.The SQL2012 server runs on EMC SAN and SQL2016 runs on Flash drive.The execution plan on both server are different.

Can you please help to troubleshoot this performance issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We ran Sp_Blitz

Comment: It'd probably help if you posted the execution plans.

Comment: Could you post the execution plans via [pastetheplan.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)? If you want to make your plans anonymous download the free version of [SQL Sentry](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) and then post your XML plans to pastetheplan. Then post back the links in your post. You might want to test the IOPS on your SSD either using IOmeter (deprecated) or [Diskspd](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DiskSpd-a-robust-storage-6cd2f223). As soon as you have enough information [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/190934/edit) it in to your question.

Comment: Submited the plan.

Comment: If by submitted, you mean you uploaded it to [pastetheplan.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), we'll need a link to it to be able to see it, as @hot2use noted.

Answer (score 0):

If the plans are different and it's the same database with the same indexes and statistics, and the same CPU and so on, it's probably because of the new cardinality estimator introduced in SQL 2014. Google provides plenty of details about it, for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn673537.aspx

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. If the plans are different and you're going from SQL 2012 to 2016 then there is a good chance it's the cardinality estimator changes that came out in 2014. Without the plans it's a bit hard to tell

Answer (score 0):

It is a cardinality issue.In short term solution we disabled it useing traceflag and in long term solution we are rewriting the code again.